# Does the convolutional layer in TensorFlow support dropout?

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering whether I can simply apply dropout to convolutions in TensorFlow. How will it be applied? Are weights of the convolution mask randomly set to zero while it 'slides' over the input?

Comment: The dropout is applied on the output of the convolution, there is no interaction with the filter weights

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can apply dropout on arbitrary input tensors. How this input was computed doesn't matter; each element of the input will simply either be kept (and scaled, see below) or set to zero.

From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout:

> With probability `keep_prob`, outputs the input element scaled up by `1 / keep_prob`, otherwise outputs `0`. The scaling is so that the expected sum is unchanged.
>
> By default, each element is kept or dropped independently.

For example:

```
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(...)
drop = tf.nn.dropout(conv, keep_prob=0.5)
```

Comment: Though some structures implement the DropoutWrapper and do different things with it. And it also seems that there are multiple ways of doing dropout in convolutional layers (standard dropout and MC dropout): https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02158

Comment: Are you referring to the DropoutWrapper for RNN (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/rnn_cell.html#DropoutWrapper)? According to its docu, it also just does "input and/or output dropout. Dropout is never used on the state." It seems other ways of doing dropout are currently not implemented in TensorFlow.